# How do you get a Javascript timer to stop once you press the link? or at least restart it?

Tags: javascript, timer, dom-events

I want to know how you get a Javascript timer to stop once you click on a link, and not necessarily the one that started it. here's the part of my code with the timer in it:

```
function doMiningcoal() {
  if (!timer_is_on) {
    timer_is_on = true;
    t = setInterval(function () {
        timedCount2();
    }, 100);                
}
} 

function timedCount2() {
document.getElementById('txt').value = d;
d = d - 1;
if (d <= -1) {
coalCount++;
xp = 15 + xp
var _message = "You have mined " + coalCount + " coal" + (((coalCount > 1) ? "s" : "") + "!") + " You have " + xp + " xp";
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = _message;
var _coal = coalCount + " Coal"
document.getElementById('coal').innerHTML = _coal
startover2();
}
}


function startover2() {
 d = 20;
clearTimeout(t);
timer_is_on=0;
doMiningcoal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is the t variable intialized outside of your function?  If not, the following functions cannot use it as it is local only to the first funciton and the t in your startover2 function is not the same (its another local one)

-edit-

Oh and you will need to use `clearInterval` since you used `setInterval`.

-edit2- -edit3, removed 1 line-

```
var t = 0;
var timer_is_on = 0;
function doMiningcoal() {    
  if (!timer_is_on) {
    timer_is_on = true;
    t = setInterval(function () {
        timedCount2();
    }, 100);                
}
} 

function timedCount2() {
    document.getElementById('txt').value = d;
    d = d - 1;
    if (d <= -1) {
        coalCount++;
        xp = 15 + xp
        var _message = "You have mined " + coalCount + " coal" + (((coalCount > 1) ? "s" : "") + "!") + " You have " + xp + " xp";
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = _message;
        var _coal = coalCount + " Coal"
        document.getElementById('coal').innerHTML = _coal
        startover2();
    }
}


function startover2() {
    d = 20;
    clearInterval(t);
    timer_is_on=0;
}
```

Comment: if u mean that another function uses it then yes. if u mean that i defined it then also yes :P

Comment: function startover() {
  c = 10;
    clearTimeout(t);
    timer_is_on=0;
    doMining();
    }

Comment: yes but do you initialize var t OUTSIDE the startover() functions?  It needs to be completely outside any function or it is out of scope.  Same goes for timer_is_on variable

Comment: yes i do, i have it at the beginning of the script along with the other variables

Comment: Ok check edit. basically changed clearTimeout to clearInterval

Comment: well you could try simply setting t=0

Comment: Oh silly me i see the problem!  At the end of the timedCount2() you call starover2(), which calls doMiningCoal(), which starts the timer again

Comment: well ya, i want it to loop, the problem is i cant get it to stop when i want it to

Comment: The interval forces the loop, your reset function 'startover2()' resets it AND restarts it at the same time. I took out 1 line should fix it now.